# Signal SIGABRT Simple Table View

Tags: ios, uitableview, sigabrt

I just followed a few steps in a tutorial to create a simple TableView with 50 rows but i get "Signal SIGABRT" :/
I connected the TableView in Storyboard with the TableViewController-Class i created.

Here's my simple code:

```
#import "TableViewController.h"

@interface TableViewController ()

@end

@implementation TableViewController

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations.
    // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;

    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
    // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 50;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath     *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    // Configure the cell...

    cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Row %i",indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to Stack Overflow! The standard methods for setting up `UITableViewCell`s changed slightly a little while ago. This means that the template code Xcode provides for tableViews uses the `-tableView: dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: forIndexPath:` method, while older tutorials and books (most of them) use `tableView: dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:`

If you want to do it the new way ( `-tableView: dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: forIndexPath`) you need to either add 
`[self.tableView registerClass:[UITableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];` in `viewDidLoad`, (or set the prototype cell reuse id in the storyboard/nib, and set the cell type appropriately - basic should do for a normal cell).

The old way (`tableView: dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:`) is normally followed by an `if` statement something like:

```
if(cell == nil) 
{
    cell = [UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}
```

(where the `\\Configure the cell. . .` comment is)

While this is really straightforward stuff, in fairness most tutorials do teach the old way, which I imagine can be confusing for a beginner if you don't notice the small difference between the two `-tableView:dequeueReusableCell` methods. A tutorial showing the new way is [here](http://kurrytran.blogspot.co.uk/2011/10/ios-5-storyboard-uitableview-tutorial.html)